# Why can APC backend cache in Phalcon not be used directly - why the need for $frontCache?

Tags: php, frameworks, phalcon

The docs offer the following approach to APC caching:

```
//Cache data for 2 days
$frontCache = new Phalcon\Cache\Frontend\Data(array(
    'lifetime' => 172800
));

  $cache = new Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Apc($frontCache, array(
      'prefix' => 'app-data'
  ));

//Cache arbitrary data
$cache->save('my-data', array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

//Get data
$data = $cache->get('my-data');
```

This seems overly complicated as opposed to the super simple approach of simply doing

```
apc_store('my-data', array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 172800);
apc_fetch('my-data');
```

Please clarify frontCache and the "prefix" key. The documentation leaves a bit to be desired in the Caching area.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that your way is simpler, but their way is more flexible, for example by using `$cache->save` instead of `apc_store` you can quickly swap from using apc to another cache system, files, memcached etc by changing one or two lines of code in one file rather than doing a find and replace through your entire app.

It might not be important in your current project, but it can make a big difference if you work on a variety different projects on different servers. By using the abstraction you could potentially reuse code as is even when the caching back end is different.

Answer (score 2):

You usually do not simply want to store "a value". You more likely want to cache a result in your web application, which is created in a certain layer in your abstracting OOP code.

So caching itself can be abstracted in OOP, and it usually fits when the rest of the code is also good OOP. And that is what you are seeing.

To be more specific:

The act of caching usually involves two components:

1. The frontend. This can be about anything that is to be cached.
2. The backend. This is the cache storage, something like APC, Memcached, or simple files.

The backend deals with talking to the storage engine. This is where your simple functions come into play to actually store the value.

The frontend allows for abstraction of which data is really stored. You can simply cache values, you might want to cache database results, you might want to cache calls to methods of a class. All of these should be transparent to your application, and probably also to your code. But it usually makes less sense to deal with the data by hand. That's what the implemented frontends are for.

I learn from the Phalcon documentation that there are not very much frontend implementations, but that there is an Interface. So the way to make use of it is to check what kind of thing you want to cache, and then implement a decorator pattern of this thing that also implements this interface.

I cannot go into more detail as I do not have any experience with Phalcon itself.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Sven, the frontend is intended to define where the data comes from (explicitly defined by the developer, from the output buffer, etc), also how data must be handled before store them into the backend and after get them from the backend. You may want to serialize the data or use a convertor such as base64/json, in an independent way of how the data is stored.